# Gzip with all cores

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I have a set of servers filled each with a bunch of files that can be gzipped.  The servers all have different numbers of cores.  How can I write a bash script to launch a gzip for each core and make sure the gzips are not zipping the same file?

Comment: Are you sure that HDD speed will not limit them?

Comment: @rulik, exactly, HDD speed will be the bottleneck or gzip would have added multi processor support long ago.

Comment: I disagree. Running gzip on a series of files in my experience pegs the CPU at 100%, disk I/O remains low. Yes, in a very extreme case you might see disk I/O become the next bottleneck, but this is an excellent reason to use those extra cores instead of running single threaded.

Comment: @Demosthenex is right.  I thought the HDD would be the bottleneck too, but top is showing that the CPU is pegged.

Comment: @Demosthenex @User1 I stand corrected. Thank you for the education!

Comment: If you had an insane number of powerful cores (ie: 64!) you might be able to generate significant I/O versus the CPU time, but it would be a very extreme case.

Comment: @Demosthenex If you had an insane number of powerful cores, you would also have an insane SLC SSD array. For reference, my desktop class SSD array writes at up to 550MB/s (but usually only consistently writes 150-300MB/s)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you are on Linux, you can use GNU's xargs to launch as many processes as you have cores.

```
CORES=$(grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo)
find /source -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P $CORES gzip -9
```

- find -print0 / xargs -0 protects you from whitespace in filenames
- xargs -n 1 means one gzip process per file
- xargs -P specifies the number of jobs
- gzip -9 means maximum compression

Comment: It's not necessary to export the variable. You should use `$()` instead of backticks. It's not necessary to use `cat` - `grep` accepts a file as an argument. GNU `grep` (if not others as well) can count, so you don't need `wc`. End result: `CORES=$(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo)`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I was lazy catting around in proc looking for it, and left it cobbled together. That's much cleaner.

Comment: If you want to reserve let's say 2 processors for other programs, you could use the following (there is probably a cleaner or more bash-ish way to do this): CORES=$(grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo | perl -ane 'print $F[0] - 2')

Comment: That makes sense too. I'd think that if they want to reserve cores, they'd just specify a number by hand instead of trying to detect.

Comment: BTW, find / xargs work on any Unix-like system (such as Mac OS X), not just on Linux. The only Linux-specific thing here is /proc/cpuinfo. If you set CORES manually (or find some other way of getting it), you can use this anywhere.

Comment: Not every unix uses the GNU implementations of find & xargs. AIX for instance has it's own xargs which doesn't support -P. Solaris, HP-UX, and several other proprietary implementations may also have the same issue. It won't work anywhere, but it should work anywhere GNU utilities are installed and cores is set manually.

Comment: You can probably just use nproc in place of parsing the output of /proc/cpuinfo, e.g. find /source -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P $(nproc) gzip -9

Comment: why don't you just use `$(nproc)` xD

Comment: @france1 - Check the date.  `nproc` was first included in coreutils 8.1 in 2009, and probably wasnt (yet) available in the OP's distribution.

Answer (score 96):

There is an implementation of gzip that is multithreaded, [pigz](http://www.zlib.net/pigz/). Since it is compressing one file on multiple threads, it should be able to read from disk more efficiently, compared to compressing multiple files at once.

Comment: I think that's a superior solution! If each block to be compressed runs in separate threads, it is superior to using something like xargs to launch one process per file! On the other hand, if you can't install custom software on $X servers, you can fall back to the xargs behavior. Great find!

Comment: This is great to know.  Unfortunately, pigz is not on our servers.  :(

Comment: Note: pigz can only do parallel compression, not decompression (more of a limitation of gz compression than pigz if I understand well). When decompression pigz does still use 4 threads, to separate reading, writing and checking.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to consider checking [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). I also found this [video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ) which seems to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Parallel mentions that it uses similar flags to xargs, ironically I found out recently that xargs now includes the ability to launch multiple processes, see my answer.