# gzip on multiple cores with pv progression bar

Tags: bash, gzip, xargs, pv

Following this 2010 question [Gzip with all cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341442/gzip-with-all-cores), I would like to `gzip` files using multiple core and indicate a progress bar with `pv` tool.

How do I improve this code?

```
CORES=$(grep -c '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo)
find /source -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 -P $CORES gzip -9
```

I would like to show remaining time and show the progression bars running in parallel.

Do you have any other best alternatives as of 2018?

Thanks.

Comment: Check GNU parallel ->  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182623/how-to-use-gnu-parallel-effectively

Comment: With parameters `-c` and `-N` you can have more than one pipeview running in parallel. In any case, you are not running `gzip` with all cores. You are running many `gzip`, one in each core. To run the gzip algorithm in many cores, use `pigz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **GNU Parallel** which has a progress bar or an `eta`:

```
find ... -print0 | parallel -0 --progress gzip -9 {}
```

Or

```
find ... -print0 | parallel -0 --eta ...
```

Or

```
find ... -print0 | parallel -0 --bar ...
```

Comment: This is my preferred solution, too.  Tip if you're using all your cores with something CPU intensive like `gzip -9`, you might want to `nice` things a bit.  You could slip a `nice -n10` either immediately before the `gzip`, or else immediately before the `parallel`, and all the child pids inherit the niceness of parallel.  Alternatively, you can run parallel with one less threads than you have cores with `parallel -j$(($(nproc)-1))`, sacrificing a little throughput.  I just prefer the `nice`ing method, so you're fully employing idle resources but yielding when normal tasks want CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really running gzip on multiple cores, you're running multiple gzip's.

`pv` runs on a pipe. I don't believe it's possible to have it run on multiple pipes at the same time and provide a summary of all of them.

Comment: I am tracking progress with `htop` with the CPU bars, but it doesn't provide the visually feedback `pv` offers